# you have to load the kernel first

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, uefi

I’m trying to resurrect a Lenovo Yoga3 that had Win10 installed over Win8, resulting in the buggiest Windows I’ve ever used.  System is 8+ yrs old and the processor’s not compatible with Win11. I made a USB boot stick for Ubuntu installation and started to try my install only to receive “you have to load the kernel first”.  I did the google dance and found enough information to set a couple of config pointers it needed and thought the whole thing was solved. I ran the wipe and install on the drive and everything was green lights, “install successful, please reboot”. On reboot (with the boot stick now removed) it dumps directly into grub2 and the “boot” command returns “you have to load the kernel first”.  Every fix I can find tells you to set the “linux root=/vmlinuz” pointer; however, the vmlinuz folder doesn’t exist.  The exit command doesn’t dump you to BIOS like it’s supposed to either - have to jump into that with F2 before grub loads, and the USB boot option isn’t there (assume because the wipe cleared the drivers).  I really just need to know what I actually need to set so grub2 doesn’t fail to boot Ubuntu.

Comment: What version Ubuntu are you running?  The 22.04 has the vmlinuz in /boot instead of root. Try linux /boot/vmlinuz  root=UUID=xxxxxxxxx  or root=/dev/sdb2 (whatever).

Comment: If you believe that your hardware needs some kind of special configuration, you really should tell us what hardware you have... Are you following the [official tutorial to Install Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop)?  If not, start over and follow the tutorial.

Comment: If 8 year old system, your specs may be better for a lighter weight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
 I use Kubuntu which is more middle weight but still has lots of features and worked on my oldest system even though retired (just as test as battery is dead and coin battery is dead, but it boots).

Comment: Since it was asked, my system is:  Lenovo YOGA 3 Pro-1370, BIOS version A6CN58WW, CPU Intel 5Y70 (1.1GHz), Hard Disk LITEON IT L8T-256L9G.

Comment: I checked /Boot (there is no /boot) and found no vmLinuz file.  I don’t believe it needs special configuration.  I believe the official tutorial instructions don’t match what’s in the 22.04 boot file.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I’ve run 20.04LTS on a laptop with lower spec than that and it ran fine; this isn’t very scientific, but my instinct is that Ubuntu always runs better than Windows on the same hardware - so if it could run windows 10 (still used on  many new machines), Ubuntu 22.04 is very likely to work at least as well, but if you’re wondering if that’s the issue, consider trying Ubuntu 20.04 (*much* lighter than Windows 10).

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately the problem turned out to be corrupted data on the boot loader USB, so I wiped it, reformatted, and remade the boot loader with a different image burner..  Voila, no more problems and my system is now running cleaner and faster than it ever did on Windows.  What Windows deemed too obsolete to support for Windows 11 seems to be pretty relevant hardware on a Linux platform…why oh why didn’t I read up on Linux sooner?

Comment: After a few days, you may accept your (upvoted) answer, gaining some rep. and getting the "solved" tag to help others.